# How to match static GTFS with GTFS-RT trip updates

Tags: sql, gtfs

Im consuming couple of different GTFS & GTFS-RT feeds, im storing this data to SQL database.

How should I match/link static GTFS data with GTFS-RT trip updates?

Im trying to display stop times for specific stop_id. Im able to get stop times from static GTFS but I want to "patch" these times with GTFS-RT trip update stop time updates.

It looks like GTFS-RT is very loosely specified, only few of the fields are mandatory. One of the GTFS-RT feeds which im consuming, has trip_id in its trip updates, another feed does not have trip_id.

**Update 4.11.2017**

I managed to match GTFS-RT trip update to static GTFS using query below. In some reason in not able to get trip_id for all trip updates. Maybe the issue is in data itself, of is there something wrong with my query?

```
const trip = await knex('trips')
  .select('trips.trip_id')
  .innerJoin('routes', 'routes.route_id', 'trips.route_id')
  .innerJoin('stop_times', 'stop_times.trip_id', 'trips.trip_id')
  .whereIn('trips.service_id', *day active service ids*)
  .andwhere('routes.route_id', tripUpdate.route_id)
  .andWhere('stop_times.departure_time', tripUpdate.trip_start_time)
  .andWhere('trips.direction_id', tripUpdate.direction_id)
  .orderBy('stop_times.stop_sequence')
  .first();
```

Comment: Yes, it's a loosely defined standard. The recent GTFS-rt 2.0 Spec clarifies this, but this is still allowed. Why? There is a use case for being able to provide service information for short-term disruptions. This is abused by a number of feeds that make it normal.

It's likely that you'll have to write some logic that can do the matching between the feed and the GTFS. But it's hard to say if that is possible without knowing what feed you're talking about.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Im using mariadb.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the

```
.andWhere('stop_times.departure_time', tripUpdate.trip_start_time)
```

clause in the select statement.

The gtfs spec states *Times must be eight digits in HH:MM:SS format (H:MM:SS is also accepted, if the hour begins with 0)* If your schedule has times like 5:37:00 and the start_time in TripUpdates is 05:37:00 your statement will not return the trip id. If this is the problem you will need to prepend times like this with "0" when adding them from stop_times.txt to the database or alternatively adjust your clause above.

Comment: In my case the problem is that there is no trip_id, and i try to match GTFS-RT TripUpdate to static GTFS with out trip_id. I added query to first post to explain how I try to make the match.